# Creating Dialog showing Zoomed Canvas Image

Tags: android, canvas

This is more an open question to point me in the right direction.
I have a Framelayout with a Canvas on it. What I am looking to do is have the user touch on the Canvas and at that point a Dialog is shown showing a Zoomed in version of what is underneath touch. Like a magnifying glass

I have a custom Dialog already created so what am looking for is how to pass the canvas to the Dialog and then zoom it in.

Relatized what I am looking for is to create a magnifying effect where the user touches

Thanks for help

Some Code what I what I have done

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//

  mainFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view_framelayout);
  drawView = new DrawView(this); // Draws an Image onto a Canvas
  mainFrame.addView(drawView);

 mainFrame.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction(); 

               switch (action) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    hitX = event.getX();
                    hitY = event.getY();

                    // Add Magifiing Glass or Pass Zoomed Image to a Dialog

                 break;

               case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                   // Dismiss the Zoomed Image
                 break;  
          }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want dialog on full-screen. Following code works for me:

```
 dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.mydialog2);
 getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```